# Serving pictures via WCF is not always working

Tags: c#, wcf

I serve pictures via WCF according to this tutorial:
https://delog.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/serving-static-web-content-using-wcf/

It works well on localhost but not always works on production: [www.findacruise.net](http://www.findacruise.net)

Chrome shows errors like these:
http://79.143.179.248:8005/wwwservice/content/2//su52ch15.zhz.jpg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

On the same laptop it works at home but does not work at workplace. So I am guessing it does not have anything to do with WCF service itself. May be "Same origin policy" issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not likely to be same-origin policy - that doesn't affect images, the error message would be different, and it would not work consistently. It's a network issue - the server is taking too long to respond. Try telnetting to that server - this will test only the TCP layers and below `telnet 79.143.179.248 8005` - note that telnet fails for me, so I think there is a problem. Does it *sometimes* work in production or *always* work in production?

Comment: What version of Asp.net and IIS are you using on the server? it's probably related to your server IIS setting.

Comment: are the pictures held in a db or just in files on the os??

Comment: @BugFinder they are files on OS

Comment: @Benjamin I have my app hosted on smarterasp.net , no idea what IIS vertion they using

Comment: @RB. Production  always works at my home. But I think never at workplace. Does it look like connection issue?

Comment: It is a connection issue - I cannot connect to the WCF server. Is it possible that you have whitelisted your home IP address, but not permitted the internet at large? Who is your hosting provider (I'm guessing Contabo?) - maybe contact them?

Comment: @RB. Yes, Contabo!  I guess you are right!!! I indeed  whitelisted my home address and IP of my site! But now I understand that whitelisting  my site IP  doesn't do the work since request goes directly from browser!! Many thanks!

Comment: @Nick Cool - I've added an answer with a suggestion of background reading - if you are doing web programming then having at least a shallow understanding of all the layers below ASP.NET is very useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the issue appears to be that you whitelisted the IP address of your home browser, and your site.

However, as discussed, you also need to whitelist the internet at large (or, more sensibly, remove whitelist blocking entirely) in order to

Telnet is a useful tool for diagnosing these sorts of issues as it removes the HTTP layer entirely, and let's you focus on the underlying network issue.

Please note - I suggest you read up on the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) of networking - it defines 7 layers from the physical transport layer (like a fiber optic cable) to the application layer (like HTTP) which provides a useful mental model for thinking about issues like this. Always try and isolate your problem to the lowest level at which it manifests :)